# Getting the diagonal elements of only part of a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor element that has shape (?, a, a, b). 
I want to convert this to a tensor of shape (?, a, b) where:

```
output[ i , j , k ] = input[ i , j , j , k ].
```

This is simple to do in numpy as I can just assign elements by looping over i, j, k. However, all manipulations must stay as Tensors in Tensorflow as its needed to evaluate the cost function and train the model.

I have already looked at [tf.diag_part()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/tensor_diag_part) but from my understanding, this cannot be specified on specific axes and must be done for the entire tensor.

Comment: how do you want to convert `output[ i , j , k ]` into `input[ i , j , j , k ]` via taking the diagonal of the second dim?

Comment: I want to go the other way, input -> output. There are many terms in input that I want to discard.

Comment: sorry, my bad, how do you want to move from input to output, do you only want the diagonal of the second dim?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. I want the final tensor to still be a rank 3 tensor with the shape above but only keep elements from the input that share an index in the middle axes (that share the same dimensions).

Comment: Further to @ImtinanAzhar s sensible question. If `b==2` then we have 4 values for `j` in the input for every 2 values of `j` in the output. How would you want to determine which to keep? The diagonal ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, like you say, `tf.diag_part` does not allow for axis, it does not seem to be useful here. This is one possible solution with `tf.gather_nd`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Input data
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None, None])
# Read dimensions
s = tf.shape(inp)
a, b, c = s[0], s[1], s[3]
# Make indices for gathering
ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(a), tf.range(b), tf.range(c), indexing='ij')
idx = tf.stack([ii, jj, jj, kk], axis=-1)
# Gather result
out = tf.gather_nd(inp, idx)

# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    inp_val = np.arange(36).reshape(2, 3, 3, 2)
    print(inp_val)
    # [[[[ 0  1]
    #    [ 2  3]
    #    [ 4  5]]
    # 
    #   [[ 6  7]
    #    [ 8  9]
    #    [10 11]]
    # 
    #   [[12 13]
    #    [14 15]
    #    [16 17]]]
    # 
    # 
    #  [[[18 19]
    #    [20 21]
    #    [22 23]]
    # 
    #   [[24 25]
    #    [26 27]
    #    [28 29]]
    # 
    #   [[30 31]
    #    [32 33]
    #    [34 35]]]]
    print(sess.run(out, feed_dict={inp: inp_val}))
    # [[[ 0  1]
    #   [ 8  9]
    #   [16 17]]
    # 
    #  [[18 19]
    #   [26 27]
    #   [34 35]]]
```

Here are a couple of alternative versions. One using tensor algebra.

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None, None])
b = tf.shape(inp)[1]
eye = tf.eye(b, dtype=inp.dtype)
inp_masked = inp * tf.expand_dims(eye, 2)
out = tf.tensordot(inp_masked, tf.ones(b, inp.dtype), [[2], [0]])
```

And one using boolean masking:

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None, None])
s = tf.shape(inp)
a, b, c = s[0], s[1], s[3]
mask = tf.eye(b, dtype=tf.bool)
inp_mask = tf.boolean_mask(inp, tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(mask, 0), [a, 1, 1]))
out = tf.reshape(inp_mask, [a, b, c])
```

EDIT: I took some time measurements for the three methods:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def f1(inp):
    s = tf.shape(inp)
    a, b, c = s[0], s[1], s[3]
    ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(a), tf.range(b), tf.range(c), indexing='ij')
    idx = tf.stack([ii, jj, jj, kk], axis=-1)
    return tf.gather_nd(inp, idx)

def f2(inp):
    b = tf.shape(inp)[1]
    eye = tf.eye(b, dtype=inp.dtype)
    inp_masked = inp * tf.expand_dims(eye, 2)
    return tf.tensordot(inp_masked, tf.ones(b, inp.dtype), [[2], [0]])

def f3(inp):
    s = tf.shape(inp)
    a, b, c = s[0], s[1], s[3]
    mask = tf.eye(b, dtype=tf.bool)
    inp_mask = tf.boolean_mask(inp, tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(mask, 0), [a, 1, 1]))
    return tf.reshape(inp_mask, [a, b, c])

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    inp = tf.constant(np.arange(100 * 300 * 300 * 10).reshape(100, 300, 300, 10))
    out1 = f1(inp)
    out2 = f2(inp)
    out3 = f3(inp)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        v1, v2, v3 = sess.run((out1, out2, out3))
        print(np.all(v1 == v2) and np.all(v1 == v3))
        # True
        %timeit sess.run(out1)
        # CPU: 1 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
        # GPU: 1.04 ms ± 93.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
        %timeit sess.run(out2)
        # CPU: 1.17 ms ± 150 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
        # GPU: 734 ms ± 17.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
        %timeit sess.run(out3)
        # CPU: 1.11 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
        # GPU: 1.41 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Seems all three are similar on CPU, but the second one is for some reason way slower in my GPU. Not sure what would be the results with float values though. Also, you could try replacing `tf.tensordot` with `tf.einsum`, for example. About the first and second one, they seem both fine, although if you are backpropagating through these operations the cost of computing the gradient may vary.